# Python: How do I print a statement when a for loop completes a number of times?

Tags: python

I have some code which mainly revoles around the following couple of lines:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from crypt import crypt
import itertools
from string import ascii_letters, digits

def decrypt(all_hashes, salt, charset=ascii_letters + digits + '-' + '/'):
    products = (itertools.product(charset, repeat=r) for r in range(10))
    chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(products)
    for i, candidate in enumerate(chain, 1):
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print ('%d th candidate: %s' % (i, candidate))
        hash = crypt(''.join(candidate), salt)
        if hash in all_hashes:

            yield candidate, hash
            all_hashes.remove(hash)

        if not all_hashes:
            return

all_hashes = ('aaRrt6qwqR7xk', 'aaacT.VSMxhms' , 'aaWIa93yJI9kU',
'aakf8kFpfzD5E', 'aaMOPiDnXYTPE', 'aaz71s8a0SSbU', 'aa6SXFxZJrI7E',
'aa9hi/efJu5P.', 'aaBWpr07X4LDE', 'aaqwyFUsGMNrQ', 'aa.lUgfbPGANY',
'aaHgyDUxJGPl6', 'aaTuBoxlxtjeg', 'aaluQSsvEIrDs', 'aajuaeRAx9C9g',
'aat0FraNnWA4g', 'aaya6nAGIGcYo', 'aaya6nAGIGcYo', 'aawmOHEectP/g',
'aazpGZ/jXGDhw', 'aadc1hd1Uxlz.', 'aabx55R4tiWwQ', 'aaOhLry1KgN3.',
'aaGO0MNkEn0JA', 'aaGxcBxfr5rgM', 'aa2voaxqfsKQA', 'aahdDVXRTugPc',
'aaaLf47tEydKM', 'aawZuilJMRO.w', 'aayxG5tSZJJHc', 'aaPXxZDcwBKgo',
'aaZroUk7y0Nao', 'aaZo046pM1vmY', 'aa5Be/kKhzh.o', 'aa0lJMaclo592',
'aaY5SpAiLEJj6', 'aa..CW12pQtCE', 'aamVYXdd9MlOI', 'aajCM.48K40M.',
'aa1iXl.B1Zjb2', 'aapG.//419wZU')

all_hashes = set(all_hashes)
salt = 'aa'
for candidate, hash in decrypt(all_hashes, salt):
    print 'Found', hash, '! The original string was', candidate
```

The program is basically a Brute Force attack and because the output can take a while I need to know if the program is still running or has crashed so I was thinking of having an output statement that says how many combinations of characters have been tried and maybe what the last tried string was but have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance for assistance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to count the candidates.

```
for i, candidate in enumerate(chain, 1):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print("%d'th candidate: %s" % (i, candidate))
    # perform actual work
```

Comment: I have edited my question to show all my code, including your answer. At the moment the code is printing out every single candidate tried, I only need it to print out one statement every nth candidate

Comment: @LWH91: on my box, it prints every 100th candidate as intended. Check your code and change the constant `100` to suit your preferences.

Comment: ah ok my bad,was going so fast thought it was every single candiate sorry. thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
PRINT_COUNT = 10
chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(products)
count = 0
for candidate in chain:
  hash = crypt(''.join(candidate), salt)
  count = count + 1
  if count % PRINT_COUNT == 0:
    print "count = " + str(count)
```

Comment: Would that print out the "count = " every time 10 more are done of just the once?

Comment: OK thanks, If i wanted to print the candidate that had just been tried im guessing i would just add something like "the last string to be tried was " + candidate

Comment: BTW - I think that larsmans answer was much better than mine - so maybe you should have accepted the other one :)

Answer (score 0):

OK,  Let's take an other example first:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(30):
    sys.stdout.write('\r%d'%i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

run it, it will print the runtime values of i.

**Attention at '\r'**

So, you can do something like this in your code:

```
chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(products)
i = 0
for candidate in chain:
    sys.stdout.write('\r%d'%i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    i += 1
    hash = crypt(''.join(candidate), salt)
```

If the output value is increasing, means that your program are running.
And even your can add your owner code to determine the remaining time.